# How to add time stamp in macro from selected excel sheet cells

Tags: sql, excel, vba, adodb

My vba code pulls data of last "11" hours from Database.
I want to pull data of my own time like "between (1/4/19 1:30 &  13/4/19 1:30)".Also want to add the data in sheet 1 like a table.
May i know how to add this custom time & make it a table using macro code.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DbConnection()
' NA Query connection with DB
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strConn As String
Dim mssql As String

strConn = "Driver={Redshift (x86)};Server=abc;Database=xyz;UID=abc;PWD=12345; Port=1234"
cn.Open strConn
cn.CommandTimeout = 60
mssql = "(using this line in SQL query here)"

where review_completed_timestamp_utc::TIMESTAMP > current_timestamp - interval'11 hour'

rs.Open mssql, cn
Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For the SQL part, since you didn't provide the names, you can do somenthing like this:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```